# How can I simulate $(this)[0].files in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drag and drop container for uploading images. Something like the option that stackoverflow has in the editor. As you know, it works in two ways:

1. drag and drop an image
2. click on the container and then a window will be opened to choose an image

Now I'm exactly doing something like that:

```
// click
$('.upload_image').on('change', function () {
    file = $(this)[0].files;
    frm = $(this).closest('form');
    addImageToInput();
    return false;
});

// drag and drop
$(".container").on('drop dragdrop', function (e) {
    file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    frm = $(this).closest('form');
    addImageToInput();
    return false;
});
```

Also I have one more function for making a preview:

```
function addImageToInput() {
    if ( file !== "" || frm !== "" ) {
        let uploadFormData = new FormData(frm[0]);
        uploadFormData.append("imageToUpload", file[0]);
        readURL(frm.find(".upload_image")[0]);
        formData = uploadFormData;
    } else {
        alert('something went wrong');
    }
}

function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('.modal-dropzone-img').html("<img src='" +  e.target.result + "' class='upload_image_preview_img'/>");
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Anyway, the preview part works well when I attach an image by using "click" *(browse)* the image, and the preview part doesn't word *(even no error throws)* when I use drag and drop approach.

---

After some tests, I figured out, these aren't equal:

```
file = $(this)[0].files;                   // click approach
file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files; // drag and drop approach
```

Any idea how can I make them equal? *(in other word, I have to make the second one like the first one, because the first one is the working one)*

Comment: when you use drag and drop this condition will be false `input.files && input.files[0]` in `function readURL(input)` because no file has been selected .

Comment: @Niladri Exactly, any solution what should I do now?

Comment: Can you try adding an else condition when the `file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files` is avalable in readURL

Comment: @Niladri emm how exactly? Can you please write an answer?

Comment: CAn you please share the HTML too

Comment: @Niladri sure https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c100c8be78896b68f5cc6480f066d479

Comment: @Niladri give me a sec, I will translate it to EN

Comment: As a side note, `$(this)[0]` is just more boring way to write `this`

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes I know, good point, thx

Comment: @Niladri The English version of my HTML https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86ca310172dd26050f1e18f21e7fe4d0

Comment: @MartinAJ please try my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the `readURL` method little bit to accept a file only, it can be drag drop or uploaded . Also `addImageToInput()` is changed accordingly

```
function addImageToInput() {
    if ( file !== "" || frm !== "" ) {
        let uploadFormData = new FormData(frm[0]);
        uploadFormData.append("imageToUpload", file[0]);
        readURL(file[0]);
        formData = uploadFormData;
    } else {
        alert('something went wrong');
    }
}

function readURL(input) {

    if (input) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('.modal-dropzone-img').html("<img src='" +  e.target.result + "' class='upload_image_preview_img'/>");
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input);
    }
}
```

here is a working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/153dp05q/

Comment: just one thing, will your code work if there be multiple of that HTML in the same page? will not files get mixed? I'm saying that because you've replaced  `frm.find(".upload_image")[0]` with `file[0]`. So what happens if there are multiple forms?

Comment: I just placed the code according to your html. for multiple forms you have  to keep a local variable to store the file and then pass it to readURL instead of keeping `file` as global variable. You need to change the code accordingly.